# Multisim simulation insight

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, simulation

I want to simulate an AC circuit in multisim. I would like hints or articles on how to simulate complex-valued impedance, for example this circuit:

[image]

I don't have an option in multisim 12.0 , to have a complex-value for the inductance or capacitor, how can i do that?
also for the analysis of this circuit to find \$V_o \$ im going with the superposition theorem:
first im turning off the voltage-dependent source replacing it with a short-circuit, turining into this circuit :

[image]

so we have in the upper-most left mesh by KVL :

\$ -4V + \frac{V_A - V_B}{1j \Omega} + \frac{V_B - V_c}{1 \Omega} = 0 \$

I'm very confused on how to extract the two more equations to solve for to find \$V_o\$ for this first superposition.

Comment: You can't simulate in AC analysis this circuit. You don't have a sinusoidal generator ...

Comment: but we have a complex-valued inductance , no? @Antonio51

Comment: If the 4 V is a DC power supply ... and you will see what happens versus time after "wiring" it ... ok. But your inductor "j omega" does not say how it would behave versus "frequency" or perhaps omega = 2* pi * f with L=1 ?

Comment: okey how can i analyse such circuitry? @Antonio51

Comment: Your equation is not true. How can we add voltages and currents ?

Comment: ah it should be \$ 4 V = V_A - V_C \$ right @Antonio51

Comment: "but we have a complex-valued inductance , no?" No. You have an imaginary-valued inductance, what is called a "pure" inductance. At DC its impedance is zero. So you can replace it with a short circuit. Then V0 is +4 volts, and point C is at 0 volts. This approach will not work in general, since there is no way to incorporate phase shift. If you really want to simulate complex impedances (inductors and capacitors) you'll need a different simulator.

Comment: is there a different between a generator outputing 4 Volts and \$4(0°) V \$? @WhatRoughBeast

Comment: I haven't a clue. I've never used Multi-Sim. However, if the simulator assumes a sinusoidal voltage, the zero-degree value will be zero, since sin(0) = 0.

Comment: ah great then can you hint me on how to find \$ V_o \$ of this circuit? @WhatRoughBeast

Comment: Find the impedance of your inductor at the frequency of interest. Characterize the voltage source as a DC voltage equal to the RMS value of the AC voltage, then solve as if it were a DC circuit. Note that this will not work for an AC source which has a DC component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "j * omega" ... is an inductance ...
And 4*V is a "step generator" ...
Then I could write these equations: Made with Maple ...
i1 (left-high loop), i2 (left low loop), i3 (right loop) are the internal currents loops.
Confirmed with simulator [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

[image]

Comment: Oh infinite thanks antonio but could you please guide me on how you came up with those equations?

Comment: whats \$ E_{in}/s \$ what is 's'?

Comment: It is the Laplace transform.  s is also j*2*pi*f when one transform the Laplace s to frequency domain.

Comment: Ein/s is the Laplace transform of the step generator of 4 V.

Comment: infinite thanks antonio!